# Group rows in UI and insert in two tables in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am currently developing a program that should create invoices and add lines based on the selection of table.

This is my table (created using DevExpress):

[image]

These are future invoice lines that have a company ID as reference.

What I want to do with the future button 'Create invoices' is create 1 invoice per selected ID and add all of the selected lines to the invoicelines table.

My tables are:

**Invoice**

InvoiceID

CompanyID

**InvoiceLines**

ID

InvoiceID

Title
....

Based on my example picture, the result I would desire is:

2 invoices with each having 2 lines added

---

The problem is that I do not know how to handle this in my code.

I currently have:

```
private void btn_ExportToDB_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> PWIDs = new List<int>();
            List<int> distinct = new List<int>();
            Dictionary<int, int> lines = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            if (gridView.SelectedRowsCount > 0)
            {

                for (int i = gridView.SelectedRowsCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {

                    int rowHandle = gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i];

                    int PWID = int.Parse(gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "pwID_PW").ToString());
                    PWIDs.Add(PWID);
                    lines.Add(rowHandle, PWID);
                    MessageBox.Show("customer id " + PWID);

                    distinct = PWIDs.Distinct().ToList();

                }
                foreach (int value in distinct)
                {

                }
            }
}
```

I tried to do the following:

1- Create a dictionary in which I put the selected rowhandle + pwID.

2- After, I loop through my dictionary and select distinct pwID values (these are used for my invoices).

3- Hereafter, I'm stuck with my invoice lines, that I can't seem to add to my invoicelines table because I think my design on handling this problem is wrong.

How could I solve this in the most efficient way?

Comment: I have described my problem (can't seem to find a way to design a method to insert values in 2 tables), I have told what I have tried so far (created dictionary) and have told that the problem hereafter is that i'm stuck with my invoicelines.

Comment: I have added my code (=my try). As you can see is that my method is not working since I'm stuck with a list of distinct values that I can not match later with an invoiceline.  hence why i asked what the best method to solve this was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can return the entire ticket objects from the selection list in your screenshot then you could run a piece of code as below;

```
    public List<Invoice> CreateInvoices(IEnumerable<Ticket> selectedTickets)
    {
        // Group tickets by company id
        return selectedTickets.GroupBy(ticket => ticket.CompanyId)
            // Convert grouping into new Invoice objects
            .Select(g => new Invoice
            {
                // Build invoice object
                CompanyId = g.Key,
                // Build invoice lines
                InvoiceLines = g.Select(line => new InvoiceLine() {Title = line.Title}).ToList()
            }).ToList();
    }
```

This shall return a IEnumerable of Invoices containing multiple InvoiceLines inside of each.